# Stream API. Collect all the values ​of the String field of the Model class into one collection, print

Tags: java, java-stream

//A task:
There is a Model class that has a field of type String. There are two container classes. Class A contains a list of objects of a particular type Model and a field of type B. Class B also contains a list of objects Model. Create a collection of objects A, fill in their internal state (list, object B), similarly to B. Collect all values ​​of the String field of the Model class into one collection, print.
wrote like this:
How to write it shorter?

```
public class Task_2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Model> modelsForB = new ArrayList<>();
    modelsForB.add(new Model("B1 "));
    modelsForB.add(new Model("B2 "));
    B b = new B(modelsForB);

    List<Model> modelsForA = new ArrayList<>();
    modelsForA.add(new Model("A1 "));
    modelsForA.add(new Model("A2 "));
    A a = new A(modelsForA, b);

    final List<String> collected = new ArrayList<>();

    Stream.of(a)
            .flatMap(item -> Stream.of(item.b))
            .flatMap(itemB -> itemB.models.stream())
            .map(model -> model.string)
            .forEach(collected::add);

    Stream.of(a)
            .flatMap(itemA -> itemA.models.stream())
            .map(model -> model.string)
            .forEach(collected::add);
    collected.forEach(System.out::println);
}

static class Model {

    String string;

    public Model(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }
}

static class A {

    private List<Model> models;
    B b;

    public A(List<Model> models, B b) {
        this.models = models;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

static class B {
    private List<Model> models;

    public B(List<Model> models) {
        this.models = models;
    }
}
```

how to write it shorter?

Comment: What language is this? Kindly edit you Question to include the language-tag.

Answer (score 2):

The static [concat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-) method could be used for that task:

```
    List<String> collected = Stream
            .concat(a.models.stream(), a.b.models.stream())
            .map(model -> model.string)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Per your question, you want to "Create a collection of objects A", so I would make sure your answer provides for this, and not just a single A.

I also threw in using Arrays.asList (for the added entries), just for brevity

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Model> modelsForB = new ArrayList<>();
    modelsForB.add(new Model("B1 "));
    modelsForB.add(new Model("B2 "));
    B b = new B(modelsForB);
    B b1 = new B(Arrays.asList( new Model("B1.1" ), new Model("B1.2" )));
    List<Model> modelsForA = new ArrayList<>();
    modelsForA.add(new Model("A1 "));
    modelsForA.add(new Model("A2 "));
    A a = new A(modelsForA, b);
    A a1 = new A(Arrays.asList( new Model("A1.1" ), new Model( "A1.2" )), b1 );
    List<A> listOfA = Arrays.asList( a, a1 );

    // If you need the collection, per the requirement, otherwise just use forEach to print instead of collect
    final List<String> collected = listOfA.stream()
            .flatMap( x -> Stream.concat( x.models.stream(), x.b.models.stream() ))
            .map(m -> m.string )
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    collected.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```